# How to move the bottom element to first line using jquery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the project using jquery scroll.
but It have some problem that I want to move the bottom element of scroll to first line of page but It isn't move the first line. just move to half of middle line.

How to solve this problem,

[image]
example)I want that the number of five is positioned to 2.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  </style>
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo" id="divDemo">
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li id="li5">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#divDemo").scrollTop(1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ps) Cycle that connected last to first is also ok 
Thanks any reply.

Comment: I've read your question five times, and still dont know what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood you, try this out:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xarov/3/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#divDemo").animate({ scrollTop: $("#li5").offset().top },"linear");
});
```

UPDATE:

CSS:

```
.demo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 110px; /* Show this little detail, it`s 10px higher */
    overflow: scroll;
  }

/* PLAY WITH THIS AROUND */
ul {
  height: 200px;
}
```

JQ:

```
$("#divDemo").animate({ scrollTop: $("#li5").offset().top - 10 },"linear");
                               /* set the offset (- 10px)---^^ */
```

Comment: It is appeared same problem. I want to move the number of 5 to start edge.

Comment: Ok.. I understand you now... you have to put an height to your `<ul>` and then you can scroll to the #5... see now the updated link

Comment: but cycle is more better. Do you know method of cycle? I want that five number next is first number of 1. It means loof of scroll.

Comment: Cycle method is I know. but I want that all number show together(1 to 5). And if the number of five is focused, next is the number of 1.

Comment: :) well... First, you welcome! Second, sorry but I don`t understand what you say... My english is really not the best... but it`s hard to know what you mean.. whatever... I never use the cycle plugin before... but if you have some problems with this or you have some "new issue" then make a "new question" in SO, so we can help you! ;)